# Can diff output maintain context?

Tags: diff

When working with git, `git diff HEAD` is helpful for seeing changes since the most recent commit.

But consider this hypothetical comment:

```
- # If user testing shows that
+ # Management insists that
  # we need more cowbell
- # please rewrite the drum
- # routine.
+ # so be sure bass is loud
+ # to enough mask.
```

I find this easier to read and understand:

```
- # If user testing shows that
- # we need more cowbell
- # please rewrite the drum
- # routine.
+ # Management insists that
+ # we need more cowbell
+ # so be sure bass is loud
+ # enough to mask.
```

Are there any tools that can produce this sort of diff, so when only a couple of interspersed lines would be the same, we minimize blocks of changes, instead of minimizing lines of changes?  Are any of these tools plug-and-play with `git diff HEAD`?  This would be helpful when reviewing changes before commit.

Comment: I don't know if such a tool exists but a visual comparison program that displays the old and the new version side by side renders it useless. And visual comparison programs surely exists (at least a dozen).

Comment: For me, side-by-side is most useful when I'm comparing two different files, or two different sections of the same file.  What I'm looking for here is comparing two different versions of the same file, and I agree side-by-side is not helpful for that.  What I'm hoping for is a tool to compare changes with more context.  Where `git diff HEAD` finds differences line-by-line, I'm hoping for a tool that would be smart enough to recognize when multiple lines of code are changing in a single logical section of code, and in that case diff by section instead of by line.